# Use of [serial number] tag

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

I'm unclear as to the actual purpose of the [serial-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial-number) tag.

Its description reads:

> A unique code assigned for identification of a single unit or device.

Of the (currently) 179 questions so tagged, they are all over the place.

- Finding the serial number of some server software
- Get disk drive serial number
- Working with a series of numbers in Excel
- Creating a unique serial number with a SQL stored procedure
- Installation error due to incorrect serial number
- etc.

This seems like a Meta Tag to me. It means many things to different people (and the description doesn't clarify it). It certainly couldn't stand alone on a question.

Is this a candidate for burnination?

Comment: I ran across this when killing serial.  It certainly needs a good washing at least.

Comment: Some of those points look more like SuperUser or ServerFault stuff.

Comment: Make this a burninate request!